# Make a non-accessible parent route in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building a React app where I have a page with tabs that display different content, so my router looks like this:

```
<Route path="/" name="home" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>
    <Route path="tabs" handler={Tabs}>
        <Route path="tab1" name="tab1" handler={Tab1}/>
        <Route path="tab2" name="tab2" handler={Tab2}/>
    </Route>
</Route>
```

This produces the following routes:

```
/
/tabs
/tabs/tab1
/tabs/tab2
```

I would like to keep the same behavior but producing the following ones (and ONLY those):

```
/
/tab1
/tab2
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n153dh8b/) demonstrating it working.

```
<Route name="root" path="/" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />
    <Route name="tabs" path="tab1" handler={Tabs}>
        <DefaultRoute name="tab1" handler={Tab1} />
        <Route name="tab2" path="/tab2" handler={Tab2} />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

Comment: With this solution, the wrapping component `Tabs` is no longer rendered.

Comment: True, so just wrap the tabs. Answer updated with fork.

Comment: Thanks @MozMorris, but this doesn't give the same behavior as the initial code. I need `Home` to be accessible in `/`, `Tab1` inside `Tabs` in `/tab1` and `Tab2` inside `Tabs` in `/tab2`. Your code makes `Tabs` a child of `Home`.

Comment: @aperezroca I've updated my answer. Pretty sure this is what you wanted.